# How do you get autofs and updatedb to work together?

Tags: linux

/etc/my.misc

```
sda1    -fstype=ntfs,user,exec    :/dev/sda1
sda3    -fstype=ntfs,user,exec    :/dev/sda3
sda4    -fstype=ntfs,user,exec    :/dev/sda4
```

/etc/auto.master

```
/my /etc/my.misc --ghost
```

When I run `locate .pdf`, I get nothing because though the mount points (sda1, sda2, ..) are created in /my - there's nothing in them till I access them. Unfortunately this is not good enough for **updatedb** and it purges its cache of /my/sdaX files. How do I prevent/solve this problem?

Comment: Most likely `/etc/updatedb.conf` has `PRUNEFS` or `PRUNEPATHS` statements dropping filesystems you're taking about. See `man 5 updatedb.conf` and of course check contents of the file `/etc/updatedb.conf`.

Comment: hi, yup but i explicitly removed autofs from there: PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media"

# Removed autofs
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre_lite tmpfs usbfs udf fuse.glusterfs fuse.sshfs curlftpfs"

Comment: it looks to be a fundamental problem.. as in.. when updatedb runs it's finding an empty /my/sda1 mount point that has been --ghost but it's not seeing the files for some werid reason